# How to update NOOBS using a Raspberry Pi without removing the NOOBS sd card

Tags: noobs

I have an old version of NOOBS (1.4) installed on my Raspberry Pi, and I want to update to a newer version.

I don't have a way to plug my micro SD card into a computer to install the new version of NOOBS on it, so I was wondering if there was a way to do it without taking the SD card out.

I tried using `apt-get dist-update` and `rpi-update` to see if they would do it, but NOOBS did not update.

Is there is a way to do this?

Comment: similar question with no answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50427/how-i-can-update-noobs

Comment: Is there a reason for upgrading NOOBS?  I thought NOOBS is just a user-friendly OS installer.  Once you've selected and installed your OS, wouldn't you just upgrade it using that OS's own mechanisms (e.g. apt-get on Raspbian)?

Answer (score 3):

Updating NOOBS is possible as of now. You have to follow the following steps:

1. Download a NOOBS .zip file from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/
2. Extract it to your Downloads folder and delete anything not noobs related
3. Make an empty folder (I'll act like your home folder is on `/home/pi`, you called your folder `h` and left it on the desktop)
4. Run `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /home/pi/Desktop/h`
5. Run `cd Downloads`
6. Run `sudo cp *.* /home/pi/Desktop/h`
7. Now make another folder (I assume you are gonna call the folder "a" and drop it on your desktop)
8. Run `sudo nano Desktop/a/installed_os.json`, then copy this content here (I assume you have Raspbian based on Debian Stretch):

---

```
[
 {
  "bootable" : true,
  "description" : "A port of Debian Stretch for the Raspberry Pi (full desktop version)",
  "folder" : "/settings/os/Raspbian",
  "icon" : "/settings/os/Raspbian/icon.png",
  "name" : "Raspbian",
  "partitions" : [
"/dev/mmcblk0p6",
"/dev/mmcblk0p7"
  ],
  "release_date" : "2018-03-13",
  "supported_models" : [
"Pi Model",
"Pi 2",
"Pi Zero",
"Pi 3",
"Pi Compute Module 3"
  ]
 }
]
```

---

9. Save it and reboot. If you did everything correctly you should have the latest version of NOOBS and your old Raspbian installation should still be bootable.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as of 2015 that updating NOOBS on an SD card using a Raspberry Pi is not possible.

See this discussion thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47878

One of the posters has this to say:

> You could try contacting the developers here -
>   https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues and ask for an upgrade
>   path.
>
> But I'm not sure what you think you might gain by updating NOOBS once
>   you have got a stable OS installed - after that it stands to one side
>   unless you need to re-install or change OS.

Then there is this issues #104 Update/Upgrade Path, https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/104 with a comment that says:

> NOOBS releases are specifically intended to be non-upgradeable - it is
>   simply a case of using whichever version is the latest release when
>   you are setting up a new SD card.
>
> This reasoning behind this is that making NOOBS upgradeable would
>   involve writing to the recovery partition which introduces the
>   possibility of the SD card becoming corrupted (which would obviously
>   be a bad thing when NOOBS is designed to be as stable as possible).
>
> It is, however, entirely feasible to create a backup of your exisiting
>   OS installation (installed under v1.2.1 or earlier) that you could
>   install via NOOBS v1.3. You can follow the guide on how to do this at
>   https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs#ho ... os-version. Remember that
>   you will need to create a tarball of both the boot and root
>   partitions.

This article [Updating Raspbian on your microSD for the Raspberry Pi 2](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/16982376-updating-raspbian-on-your-microsd-for-the-raspberry-pi-2) describes updating Raspbian however mentions to update NOOBS requires using a PC or Mac to download NOOBS and put it on an SD card.

The commands you mention are to update the installed operating system and not NOOBS.

Answer (score 0):

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45250/8697 for my earlier answer to a question on NOOBS.

Most of the issues still apply although [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) which is based on NOOBS does have some update capability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upgrade NOOBS or PINN (enhanced version of NOOBS). NOOBS and PINN both uses two partitions on the Pi's boot system SD Card, /dev/mmcblk0p1 (a vfat boot partition) and /dev/mmcblk0p5 (a Linux display/selector/(/media/pi/SETTINGS) partition). To list files in NOOBS/PINN boot partition, it has to be mounted, `sudo mkdir /mnt/d1; sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/d1` then `ls -l /mnt/d1`.

I would suggest to make a back up or your system first as if any thing goes wrong the only other recovery would be a fresh install.

Get the lastest copy of NOOBS `wget -O NOOBS_lite.zip https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_lite_latest` or PINN `wget -O PINN.zip https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinn/files/latest/download`

Make subdirectory `mkdir NOOBS` or `mkdir PINN`. Change to subdirectory `cd NOOBS` or `cd PINN` and unzip `unzip ../NOOBS_lite.zip` or `unzip ../PINN.zip`.

The `runinstaller` in the file `recovery.cmdline` is for the new install. We are updating, not installing a new systems. THIS OPTION HAS TO BE REMOVED, `vi recovery.cmdline` (Enter) cmd `dw` to delete word `:wq` (Enter) to save and exit (`:q!` (Enter) to quit without saving if things goes wrong) (See WARNING at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=142574&start=200#p1239359).

Remove the old NOOBS/PINN files from /dev/mmcblk0p1 that is mounted on /mnt/d1 previous, `sudo rm -R /mnt/d1/*` and copy the new files `sudo cp -R * /mnt/d1/`. Cleanup and sync, `cd ../`, `sudo sync; sudo umount /mnt/d1; sudo rmdir /mnt/d1`, `rm -R NOOBS*` or `rm -R PINN*`.

Reboot `sudo reboot` and and first boot on the new NOOBS or PINN and then to previous OS boot.